# Google Geolocation Problem with Beautiful Widgets

Tags: geolocation

After boot Beautiful Widgets shows a Google Geolocation Problem notification and tells me that Google can't find my location based on the given GPS coordinates.

Beautiful Widgets suggests that:

"- Android Geolocation system is temporarily down
- A bad GPS fix has been provided by your phone

If that still does not work, disable geolocation in the settings."

How can I fix this? Not only is it bothersome, it is also draining my phone's battery at an alarming rate.